# Add localized language app descriptions on app store

Tags: localization, app-store, cocoonjs

I have an app, written in JavaScript and built into Objective C by http://cocoon.io

In other words, I can not edit the C files of the build. Now, I want to do the simplest thing on the world - to add translated app description in multiple languages. On the play store all I need to do is to select and add a new language from the drop down menu and add the corresponding description.

On apple, however, from what I read, I need to set the list of languages available in the drop down from the build. I can't express enough how silly is this!!!

In the iTunes store on the "Localizable Information" language drop down I have only and only English.

Any workaround about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you just want to add localised App Store descriptions for your app. This works similar in iTunes Connect as it would with the Google Play console. (It's different if you want to localise your app itself. For more info check the [official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html).)

1) Log into **iTunes Connect** and choose your app

2) Click on the **languages dropdown** on the right - default shows your primary language - and click on the little **blue "+" to add languages**.

[image]

3) You can now **add specific/translated metadata** for the new languages. (App description, keywords, marketing URL, support URL; even screenshots if you wish)

*Few notes*:

- There is no "automatic" translation service integrated into iTunes
  Connect. You need to manually get the metadata translated and insert
  it on iTunes Connect.
- You can only add new languages, when your app
  is in an editable state. If your app is currently on the store, you    need to add a new version to add new languages to it.
- Find more information on what you can localise and which languages are available at the iTunes Connect Developer guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH18-SW3

Comment: Thanks, mate! I've actually figured out that myself - my bad. It really works!